# The Mystery of an Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm developing a *Model View Controller (MVC)* project.  Due to the size and complexity, I'm trying to ensure organization.  I've managed to stumble on a unique quandary, one that has left me quite stumped. My issue is drawn from a *Jquery Rotator* that I'm integrating into my site.

My *Solution Explorer*:

- Content :  This particular folder contains three direct *sub-folders* `Images`, `Scripts`, and `Stylesheets`.

Those three sub-folders contain more specific and honed in details, an example would be the `Scripts` contains another folder called `Rotator` for this *jQuery* implementation.

So the dilemma occurs inside the *View*.

An example within this *View*:

```
<div class = "banner-style">
     <div id = "Infinite-Banner">
          <div class = "banner-container">
                <div class = "slides">
                      <img src = "~/Content/Images/Banner/Slides/One.jpg">
                      <img src = "~/Content/Images/Banner/Slides/Two.jpg">
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So within this structure it doesn't appear to load the *Images*. Though it is properly mapped to the directory.  But if you use the same structure above but change the `img` portion to:

```
<div class = "slide-one" />
<div class = "slide-two" />
```

Then in a the correlating *Stylesheet*, simply define a `background: url(~/Content/Images/Banner/Slides/One.jpg);` for the `slide-one` Element it magically appears.

**So this makes me believe that it is due to nesting**. But doesn't quite make sense, as this will force me to build an inner element between the `div slides` so that I can generate the proper affects.

The other idea would be to create a `model` that maps all the relational image data; but that seems like an awful lot of work.

Is this a limitation or an issue specific to my machine?  What would be the best work around to such an issue?  Is this indeed due to the structure I've taken to my folders?

Comment: When setting attribute values in the markup, can you remove the space between the attribute, equal sign and value?

Comment: Is this an MVC3 or MVC4 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `Url.Content` method:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/banner/slides/one.jpg")" />
```

You didn't post what the actual URL is being built as, but, I would guess that the path is wrong because whatever controller you're hitting is being used in the relative path.